# Android Push Notification Message Cut off

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi im working on a project that uses push notifications to push out information in a text format. Only when i receive the push notification the text is cut off and replaced with "..."

Im using the NotificationCompaq builder to build my notifications when the app receives the information from the receiver.

Here is my GCMBroadcastReceiver Im pretty sure the issue is in the Builder but Im not sure what i need to do to fix it.

```
import utilities.CommonUtilities;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

/**
 * Handles the incoming messages from the server.
 *
 */
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else {
            sendNotification(message);
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle(CommonUtilities.pushTitle)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 1000)
                        .setVibrate(CommonUtilities.pattern);


        Log.d(TAG, "Notification built " + mBuilder.toString());


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());


        Toast.makeText(ctx, "New Message: " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated thanks.

**Edit**
Ive checked the Message received from the GCM before my app builds the notification and i am receiving the full message there is nothing being cut off during the receiving of the message so it is definitely something to do with the Notification builder. I Just cannot seem to figure out whats causing it to do that.

Comment: How long are your messages? If I remember correctly, they're limited to 2Kb.

Comment: they are no more than 140 characters ive limited it so that the messages cant be excessively large and annoying

Comment: Ive checked the message before the notification is built and it is receiving the full message so i dont think it is a data isssue